# Pandas: Assign same cluster id to records based on common groups in different columns

Tags: python, pandas, graph, group-by, connected-components

I have a dataframe like this:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 222 | 111 |
| 2 | 111 | 222 | 222 |
| 3 | 111 | 111 | 555 |
| 4 | 222 | 222 | 444 |
| 5 | 222 | 333 | 111 |
| 6 | 222 | 444 | 333 |
| 7 | 333 | 555 | 777 |
| 8 | 444 | 666 | 777 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': [111,111,111,222,222,222,333,444], 
  'B': [222,222,111,222,333,444,555,666],
  'C': [111,222,555,444,111,333,777,777]
})
```

I want to create new column 'cluster' and assign same id to records which are connected directly or through common group in one of the columns.
Meaning, here for example,  we see that first 3 elements connected by same group in 'A', but they also connected to other records which have same groups '222', '111' in column 'B'. And all records which have '111', '222', '555' in column 'C'.
So basically, all first 6 elements should have same cluster Id.

| index | A | B | C | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 222 | 111 | 1 |
| 2 | 111 | 222 | 222 | 1 |
| 3 | 111 | 111 | 555 | 1 |
| 4 | 222 | 222 | 444 | 1 |
| 5 | 222 | 333 | 111 | 1 |
| 6 | 222 | 444 | 333 | 1 |
| 7 | 333 | 555 | 777 | 2 |
| 8 | 444 | 666 | 777 | 2 |

Records 4-6 are connected to 1-3 as they form a group in column A and they are connected to previous records through columns B and C.

I was playing with multiple consequent apply functions on pairs of columns, but now thinking of applying connected components here, but can't figure out how to do that.

Also, the main problem is that this dataset is huge, > 30 000 000 records.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed achieve this using [`networkx.connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html), after reshaping your DataFrame to build the consecutive pairs of edges. This won't be so fast with 33M rows though:

```
import networkx as nx

tmp = (df
   .melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='source')
   .assign(target=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0)['source'].shift())
   .dropna(subset=['source', 'target'])
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['source', 'target'])
)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp)

groups = {n: next(iter(g)) for g in nx.connected_components(G) for n in g}

df['cluster'] = df['A'].map(groups)
```

Output:

```
     A   B    C cluster
0  111  02  001     002
1  111  02  002     002
2  111  01  005     002
3  222  02  004     002
4  222  03  001     002
5  222  04  003     002
```

Graph:

[image: connected components]

##### considering identical values in different columns as different nodes:

There are several options, an easy one is to use strings and to prefix the column name in the node

```
tmp1 = df.astype(str).radd([f'{c}|' for c in df])

tmp = (tmp1
   .melt(ignore_index=False, value_name='source')
   .assign(target=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0)['source'].shift())
   .dropna(subset=['source', 'target'])
   .drop_duplicates(subset=['source', 'target'])
)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp)

groups = {n: i for i, g in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G), start=1)
          for n in g}

df['cluster'] = tmp1['A'].map(groups)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C  cluster
0  111  222  111        1
1  111  222  222        1
2  111  111  555        1
3  222  222  444        1
4  222  333  111        1
5  222  444  333        1
6  333  555  777        2
7  444  666  777        2
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mozway!
I'm not familiar with Networkx, could you explain reshaping of dataframe? I start playing with Networkx and just added edges without transformations, is it incorrect? 
```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='A', target='B')
G.add_edges_from(zip(df['B'], df['C']))
components = nx.connected_components(G)
# Map each node to its component ID
component_map = {}
for i, component in enumerate(components):
    for node in component:
        component_map[node] = i
df['cluster'] = df['A'].map(component_map) 
```

Comment: `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` already creates the edges, you don't need to add them manually. Here I'm just adding edges between successive values. You do not need to have **all** edges for a connected component analysis. If `A -> B -> C` it's sufficient to know the `A,B` and `B,C` edges to determine that all 3 nodes are connected. The transformation is a `shift` to form the successive edges per row.

Comment: Found one issue - in this solution we are connecting together records even if they have same value in different columns, meaning that each columns should have all unique values between itself. But it's not always the case..(

Comment: @Alex_Y can you update your example to illustrate what you want? It's not clear

Comment: Updated. But if it's very hard to do, anyway I can factorize datatframe and assign all unique values across dataframe.

Comment: @Alex_Y I see what you mean, `111` in `A` shouldn't be considered the same node as `111` in B? Then yes, one option is to `factorize` in a way to have unique factors per column. Another approach could be to use a tuple of `(colname, value)` as node, but that will be expensive! I'll try to update.

Comment: @Alex_Y see update with an easy approach using strings, I've not tested `factorize`, it might be faster. You'd need to compute it one column as a time and add the max factor of the previous column to ensure unique factors. Or `stack` and compute the `factor`/`group` per combination of column/value.

Comment: Can you help please to adapt solution for cases when we have NaN in some columns? Especially in 'A' - we can't map groups in that case.. 
Or.. I can replace NaNs with incrementing max cluster value)

Comment: Can't you drop the NaN (if not relevant) or convert them to string (if relevant)?

Comment: No, can't drop - because it could be none in one column but this record could be related to others through other columns. if replace with string - it will create a lot of fake connected components (connected through same string (NaN)). But yes, replace with incrementing max value is working, so no problem)

Comment: You can then likely convert NaN to string and remove the node from the graph before computing the connected components